# How do we upgrade from OJet ( Oracle JavaScript Extension Toolkit) 7.x to 10.0? Where do we find the oraclejet.zip for v. 10.0?

Tags: oracle-jet

We are trying to upgrade existing application that makes use of OJet 7.x.
Since we will need to upgrade to latest version, we found this documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/jet/10/develop/work-oracle-jet-base-distribution.html#GUID-7A0CF9DE-6CE1-4A42-B380-5A06D81291EC

We normally download oracle Jet distributable via the website, but cannot find it now.
Unzip oracletjet.zip and update local project.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please review this page and see if this works for you [Oracle JavaScript Extension Toolkit(JET)](https://www.oracle.com/in/tools/downloads/jet-downloads.html)

Comment: already tried installing npm, and installing @oracle\ojet-cli... But i am lost in trying to find the oraclejet.zip (oracle jet base distribution). Also tried to check help via ojet --help,  I haven't figured out yet, how I can update current  application using cli. 

Since we just usually update the application using the oraclejet.zip of the target version, I will need to get the oraclejet.zip, same in :

https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/jet/10/develop/work-oracle-jet-base-distribution.html#GUID-1F2206F1-C752-4D7A-9076-979CD0B02E9E

Can you tell what im missing?

Comment: trying npm install oracle\oraclejet-tooling